# Shipping MYSQL Dabatase with product

Tags: mysql

Can anyone help me understanding what can I do if I want to ship a MYSQL database along with a web based software I have. I am using a free version of MYSQL 5.1. All I want is the client should not able able to get the access to my database/tables, but my application should be able to access database when installed on the client machine.

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: you want your client to install the software on his server but not to be able to access the db? rather odd scenario. can you describe more precicely what you want to do? shouldn't you consider to host the application yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run the database on the client machine or host it yourself, depending on the circumstances, but if you have a php application or something then the client could just take the connection details out of it, so it doesnt matter, he can access the database anyways.
If its not like that, you can do it as you like, if you can have you own database username and password. The local hosting might be somewhat faster and more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.

I will have a .Net based application pointing the DB. I am planning to package the database too along with my application installer which will actually install MYSQL on the client server. Still I want to restrict the client from looking into my DB structure or records. Possible?

Comment: Jea if he does not have the login for the DB and he cant get it out of your App (closed source) or somewhere else, he cant access the Database. Should work

Comment: I find this a rather strange scenariol! and what client would like to install a software that installs mysql on the server??? that would most probably break all kinds of other things running there... I would never want a software that installs mysql on my server!